# add a popup to this default.aspx page

Tags: asp.net, popup

i have that small website where i want to add a popup ( an image with a link and the close button ),
but i cant find the good code for it can someone help?
i tried several on the internet but without lock.
sorry for the post but i never worked on aspx so its all new to me.

```
<%@ page language="VB" autoeventwireup="false" inherits="_Default, ctts_2016" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<%= CurrentPageData.LanguageCode %>">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title id="meta_Title" runat="server">CTTS - Trucks and trailers</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="" id="meta_Keywords" runat="server" />
        <meta name="description" content="" id="meta_Description" runat="server" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="<%= CurrentPageData.LanguageCode %>" />
        
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

        <%--indexing--%>
        <%= formatAllowIndexing()%>
        <%--Css--%>
        <%= Functions.InsertCSS("css/bootstrap", False)%>
        <%= Functions.InsertCSS("css/font-awesome", False)%>
        <%= Functions.InsertCSS("css/animate", False)%>
        <%= Functions.InsertCSS("css/settings", False)%>
        <%= Functions.InsertCSS("css/owl.carousel", False)%>
        <%= Functions.InsertCSS("css/owl.theme", False)%>
        <%= Functions.InsertCSS("css/magnific-popup", False)%>
        <%= Functions.InsertCSS("css/select2", False)%>
        <%= Functions.InsertCSS("css/preset", False)%>
        <%= Functions.InsertCSS("css/style", False)%>
        <%= Functions.InsertCSS("css/responsive", False)%>
        <%= Functions.InsertCSS("css/wide", False)%>
        <%--<%= Functions.InsertCSS("css/color", False)%>--%>
        <%= Functions.InsertCSS("css/ttc", False)%>

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <%= Functions.InsertJS("js/responsive/html5shiv", False)%>
            <%= Functions.InsertJS("js/responsive/respond", False)%>
        <![endif]--> 

        <%--Javascript--%>
        <%= Functions.FormatSiteUrl()%> <%--deze regel NIET verwijderen (zorgt ervoor dat javascript functies de siteurl instelling uit de webconfig kunnen gebruiken)--%>

        <%--google--%>        
        <%= Functions_Site.formatGoogleWebmasterTools()%> <%--deze regel voegt de nodige code toe om een site te "koppelen" aan een Google Webmaster Tools account--%>
        <%= Functions_Site.formatGoogleAnalitics()%> <%--deze regel voegt de nodige code toe om een site te "koppelen" aan een Google Analytics account--%>

        <link rel="canonical" href="<%= CurrentPageData.GetPageLink() %>"/>

        <%--favicon--%>
        <link type="image/x-icon" href="<%= Functions.SiteUrl %>images/favicon.ico" rel="icon"/>
        <link type="image/x-icon" href="<%= Functions.SiteUrl %>images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="frmXenia" runat="server"> <%--deze form NIET verwijderen, is verplicht bij asp.net pagina's--%>
            <%--<div class="preloader">
                <img src="<%= Functions.SiteUrl %>images/preloader.gif" alt="LOADING..." />
            </div>--%>

            <!--wrapper-->
            <div class="box">
                <!--header top bar-->
                <section class="headerTopbar">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <%--<p class="headTOpinfo">
                                    C.T.T.S - Cars, Trucks & Trailers Service
                                </p>--%>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-right resMobcenter">
                                <asp:Literal ID="ltlLanguages" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </section>
                
                <!--header middle-->                
                <section class="headerMiddle">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <a href="<%= Functions.SiteUrl %>">
                                        <img src="<%= Functions.SiteUrl %>images/logo.png" alt="C.T.T.S - Trucks and Trailers" />
                                    </a>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12 text-right">
                               <div class="singlehmib">
                                    <i class="fa fa-mobile-phone"></i>
                                    <h2>Tel</h2>
                                    <h4>+32 (0) 56 61 01 61</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="singlehmib">
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                                    <h2>Email </h2>
                                    <h4>info@ctts.be</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                
                <!--header-->
                <header class="header">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                                <nav class="mainnav">
                                    <div class="logoMobile hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-md"></div>
                                    <div class="mobileMenu hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-md">
                                        <span></span>
                                        <span></span>
                                        <span></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <asp:Literal ID="ltlMenu" runat="server" />
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 hidden-xs"> <%--verbergen op mobiel--%>
                                <%--<div class="searchHeader"> 
                                    <a href="#" class="headerSeacBtn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                    <div class="searchMe">
                                        <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
                                        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                                        <a href="#" class="cluseSearch"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>--%>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
                
                <!--content-->
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phContent" runat="server" />

                <%--footer--%>
                <footer class="footer">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <asp:Literal ID="ltlFooter" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>

                <!--copyright-->
                <section class="copyright">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                C.T.T.S - Cars, Trucks & Trailers Service
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-right">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            
            <a href="#" id="backToTop" class="hideit"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>
</div>
            <%--javascript--%>
            <%= Functions.InsertJS("js/jquery", False)%>
            <%= Functions.InsertJS("js/bootstrap", False)%>
            <%= Functions.InsertJS("js/jquery.themepunch.revolution", False)%>
            <%= Functions.InsertJS("js/jquery.themepunch.tools", False)%>
            <%= Functions.InsertJS("js/owl.carousel", False)%>
            <%= Functions.InsertJS("js/jquery.magnific-popup", False)%>
            <%= Functions.InsertJS("js/mixer", False)%>
            <%= Functions.InsertJS("js/select2.full", False)%>
            <%= Functions.InsertJS("js/theme", False)%>
            <%= Functions.InsertJS("js/stickyfooter", True)%>
            <div id="divRenderTime" runat="server" style="margin: 0px auto;">
                page rendered in: <asp:literal ID="ltlExecutionTime" runat="server" />ml>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

someone can help with the popup code

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using jQuery.ui.

There is a good chance you have jQuery installed, and probably use it. Since darn near everyone has jQuery, then add jQuery.ui.

I do like the look + feel of Bootstrap dialogs, but using them is worse then a trip to the dentist.

And even better, you can use such jQuery.ui dialogs for existing asp.net buttons.

So, say like this:

[image]

So, the approach is this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdTestDialog" runat="server" 
            Text="Show dialog"
            CssClass="btn"
            
            OnClientClick="MyDialog();return false"
            
         />

        <div id="MyCoolDialog" style="display:none">
            <div style="text-align:right">
                <h5>Enter First Name&nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </h5>
                <h5>Enter Last Name&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </h5>
            </div>

        </div>


        <script>

            function MyDialog(btn) {

                var myDialog = $("#MyCoolDialog");
                myDialog.dialog({
                    title: "Enter Name",
                    modal: true,
                    width: "400px",
                    position: { my: "right top", at: "right bottom",of: btn },
                    buttons: {
                        ok: function () {
                            myDialog.dialog("close")
                        }
                    }
                })
            }

        </script>
```

So, we have a simple asp.net button.

The thing we pop is to be placed in a div. What you put inside that div is quite much up to you.

So, above results in this:

[image]

So, just create a simple "div" with whatever you want inside (say you link).

Then add jQuery.ui to your project.

And thus you can now pop any content.

I popped the dialog to the lower right of the button click. But, if you remove the position code, then the dialog will show center of page.

So, remove this:

```
position: { my: "left top", at: "right bottom",of: btn },
```

And dialog will center in page.

So, setup, get, obtain, enjoy a good dialog system. Once you get one working, then of course you have a great setup and system to use for any of your dialogs in a application.

While there are quite a few choices of what system to use, the jQuery.ui dialog hands down seems about the best choice.

I don't care too much for the default layout with that 1980's style title bar (looks a bit like Windows 3.1). But, with some efforts, you can style up the dialog to look as good as say any Bootstrap dialog.

jQuery.ui dialogs I feel are the better choice.

- They have great position options - bootstrap ones don't
- They allow  you even load content from another page - bootstrap ones don't
- They just work, and work on a simple click event (not some insane asylum approach with a boatload of class(s) that you apply to a div, and THEN hope on they pop when you want them to.
- They are draggable like desktop software.
- They can be "model" and nicely grey out/disable the background
- I can type on for 100+ more pages, but until bootstrap dialogs gain a normal type click and show, and normal approach to development, then jQuery.ui dialogs wins hands down as better choice.
- And jQuery.ui plays nice with pop-up blockers.